# Setting id's as keys Angularfire

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I hope I'm not duplicating any question here but I can't seem to find the answer for this.

I've been trying to structure my firebase data like it's written in this link. 
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html

I have groups which will contain users.
And as I can understand it, the best way is to do that is to set id's as keys and setting the values to true for example.

Like this

`group/users/$id:true`

my problem is, how do I set the id's as keys?

after creating a user I can access the id of that user with `user.uid` for example.

My first thought was that I could just use that variable as a key and setting the value to true, like this `user.uid: true` and then use `.set` or similar.

But I get an error when doing this saying I can't have a dot in the key, so I tried doing it like this

```
var uid = user.uid;
uid : 'true'
```

but the result of this is in firebase is just a key named uid with value true.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've already tried `firebaseRef.child(uid).set(true)`? There's about a million ways--well, a handful--to get this done in AngularFire. What is the actual use case here? What does the data look like? What does the code look like?

Comment: Such a stupid mistake, i thought i needed to provide the complete thing within the .set() so of course your line worked, at least now i know how to use that! Thanks! :)

Comment: Aha! Well great work. Glad it's resolved.

Comment: Was my latest two questions to unclear, havent got any answers or comments on them. Would be really happy if someone could look at them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30775083/user-groups-in-angularfire, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30756124/filtering-with-multiple-values-angularfire